# Stars "sub-bottom" in Assembly code

Tags: loops, assembly, x86, inline-assembly, microprocessors

my question is this:

For example i will enter 6 and i wanna see stars sub bottom until the 6.  for example:

```
First line:(*)
Second: (**)
3th (***)
4th.(****)
5th(*****)
6th.(******)
```

How can i do that with assembly code ?
i tried this but i can not run it.

```
N EQU 6
MOV AX,0B800H
MOV DS,AX
MOV CL,'*'
MOV CH,00001111B
MOV BX,0h
MOV AX,1
FIRST_LOOP:
MOV DX,0
SECOND_LOOP:
MOV [BX],CX
ADD BX,2
INC DX
CMP DX,AX
JB SECOND_LOOP
ADD BX,158
SUB BX,AX
SUB BX,AX

INC AX
CMP AX,N
JB FIRST_LOOP
RET
```

Comment: What happens when you try to compile/run this?  Also, there are a lot of unexplained constants in this code.  If you could add some comments, it would be easier to see what is going on.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

i took unwanted result :/

But i can not see my mistake

Comment: agreeing with @superultranova (!)  First, Could you please comment your code ? Bonus points if you put a comment for each line. Secondly, could you add the tag `x86` ? I think this will help you get a lot more response; plus it will quite likely show you your own answer before you finish.

Comment: thank you for your answer.I need just this screen in my program:

*
**
***
****
*****
******

Something like that.But it must be sub-bottom.I hope,i explained my problem :)

Comment: @gingarr We understand what you want to happen, however, the code isn't self explanatory.  For instance, what are you moving into AX on line two, what does 0B800 represent?  What about the constant on line 5?  Also, what are you doing to print to screen, I don't see any calls or interrupts.

Comment: @superultranova A very long time ago (ie pre-protected mode os), you could display text on pcs by writing directly to video memory (typically located at B800).  In text mode (the default), each character took 2 bytes (ascii + attribute).  In this code, we see cl being written to DS:BX, then we add 2 to bx to go to the next char.  The 158 is intended to go to the next line (80 char display * 2bytes per char minus the single '*' written on line 1), but since BX will have a different value each loop, using 158 only works on the first line.  I'm not sure what OS/hw might still support this. FWIW.

Answer (score 0):

```
ADD BX,158
SUB BX,AX
SUB BX,AX
```

Just change 158 into 160. It'll work!

```
CMP AX,N
JB FIRST_LOOP
```

Use `jbe` to have the sixth line.

Answer (score 0):

From your question's closing statement "i tried this but i can not run it", I infer that you are having trouble executing the program. Most modern operating systems like Windows, Linux, etc. run in protected mode and does not allow programs to directly access an arbitrary memory location. Your program does try to access absolute addresses and that could be the problem.

**Your program tries to modify memory at 0B800H which used to hold the video-card (text-mode) data in legacy systems.**

### Fix

If I have correctly identified the problem, using some emulator like dosbox, bochs etc. should allow you to run your program (for learning purposes only). But you should know that any system-wide change you make through programming inside any of these is going to be confined to the emulator environment. You can google for the emulator names to find more information on these emulators (and especially their limitation which will determine their suitability to your purpose).

#### Code edits

You should also incorporate code-edits suggested by @user3144770 to get the desired output:

1. ;;; screen-size is 80char wide, with each character having 2byte data
   ;;; (1 byte for the character itself and 1 for the attributes) 2x80(=160).

   > ADD BX,<strike>158</strike> 160   
   >      SUB BX,AX 
   >      SUB BX,AX
2. ;;; You start counting at 1, `MOV AX,1`, so to get the sixth line
   ;;; printed you should loop till count is equal to 6 (inclusive).

   > CMP AX,N 
   >      <strike>JB</strike> JBE FIRST_LOOP